# Very simple question about awaiting a task async

Tags: .net, async-await, asp.net-core-3.1

I cannot seem to figure out one simple thing after reading and watching videos for hours.

Is there a difference between these two or does the compiler do this for me? Do I actually need to do Task.Run every time I await?

```
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await _databaseConnectionHelper.SetDatabaseConnectionFromOrganization(orgId);

            }).Wait();
```

and

```
await _databaseConnectionHelper.SetDatabaseConnectionFromOrganization(orgId);
```

Also, I see some people say to always use ConfigureAwait(false) and some say not to. I can't seem to get a straight answer.

Thanks for helping a newbie. I really am trying to find this and have spent hours studying await/async for the last couple of days. I understand it much better than I did before, but some of the basics are escaping me.

BTW this is in a .NET Core 3.1 project if that makes a difference. My application is basically CRUDs that hit a database and display them on a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a difference between these two or does the compiler do this for me?

Yes, there is. First one will block current thread until `Task.Run` is finished, second one will allow current thread be reused if your call is asynchronous. So it can lead to noticeable performance degradation in some cases for the first one compared to the second.

> Do I actually need to do Task.Run every time I await?

No, you don't, and I would say you should (almost) never do something like this in modern codebase.

> I see some people say to always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` and some say not to

It is [a general rule of thumb](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html#you-dont-need-configureawaitfalse-but-still-use-it-in-libraries) when you are writing some library which can be used by anyone (UI app, or legacy ASP.NET app, or anywhere else there may be a context) . But in you case if you have "vanilla" ASP.Net Core 3.1 webapp you don't need (see the already linked post).

Also if you want to go deeper about `ConfigureAwait`see [this post by Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)  and [this one by Stephen Toub](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thank you, Guru, for simply answering the question and not make me feel like I could find the answer elsewhere. I really tried and just couldn't find anything conclusive. Good news for me means I am doing it correctly in my website everywhere. It is basically async/await on every method. It was working, but I was worried I was going into a code review and get torn to pieces as tends to happen lol. Thanks again!

Comment: @gecclesinc was glad to help. `async-await` is not an easy topic especially first time you bump into something like it and there is a lot info about it and it can be overwhelming.